# How do i get data from a form , convert it to an int and pass it to a java class?

Tags: java, jsp, parseint, getparameter

**.jsp**

```
 <% MainProgram.MainAverageProgram myProgram
             = new MainProgram.MainAverageProgram();  %>

 <% out.println("" + myProgram.getForm()); %> 
 // returns simple form with parameter user  

 <% myProgram.comAvgerage(request.getParameter("user"));%>
```

I wish to get the user field and convert it to an int.
Then I want to use this int in  a java class,
do i convert it in the jsp file  or in a java method ?

**java method**

```
public String comAvgerage( String number )
{    
    int user = Integer.parseInt(number);       
    return user;
}
```

i dont understand why this fails, it will always be null when the program runs right ?

Comment: Please be clear with your question . your language is totally in-descriptive

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect a `String` method to return `int` variable . should be identified in the compile time itself.

```
public int comAvgerage( String number )
{    
    int user = Integer.parseInt(number);       
    return user;
}
```

should work as expected , however i dont understand your question exactly . comment to my answer for further questions on this

NOTE:

`request#getParameter` is used to get the values from the request

Comment: request.getParameter("user"); gives me a String right ? so i should be able to pass this to a method that takes a string as a parameter ?

Comment: But you cant return an integer variable from a java method which returns string

Comment: No if you make it as void , you cant return. if you wish not to return you can do it .. still i cant understand what you are trying to . can you please elaborate it clearly in your question

Comment: i simply want to get input from a form and use it as an int

Comment: A nice tutorial on jsp , servlets here http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html ..read it through

Answer (score 0):

A wrong use of request.getParameter method, since it is used to obtain parameters from a get request,here you can't get the user field value from your input form which is actually in a post request.
try request.getAttribute("user")